# Activate WPF Window without losing focus on previous application/window

Tags: wpf, window, focus

I have a WPF window in application which I Activate on some specific scenarios by calling `MainView.Activate();` and `MainView.BringIntoView();` method. it also sets focus on this 'MainView' window.

But my requirement is this window should not get Focus. i.e. my cursor should still remain on previous application(notepad,word etc..)

I tried using `MainView.ShowActivated="False"` but it didn't work.
Do I need to use HwndSource as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/09/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-3-focus-and-activation.aspx) or what?

Code I have used after Kent's help (Its working only if Window is minimized):

```
IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
            const short SWP_NOMOVE = 0X2;
            const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
            const short SWP_NOZORDER = 0X4;
            const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses(".");

            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

I Have Win32 helper class for such situation here is listing for your case

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace your.namespace {
    public static class Win32 {
        public static void ShowWindowNoActive( Window window) {
            var hwnd = (HwndSource.FromVisual(window) as HwndSource).Handle;
            ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWindowCommands.SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);

        private enum ShowWindowCommands : int {
            SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's call the window that you want to show without focus: YourWindow. Add the following code:

> YourWindow.ShowActivated = false;
>
> YourWindow.Owner = TheOtherWindowThatWillStilHaveFocus;

First line you can also set from XAML.

Comment: The ShowActivated attribute on XAML works perfectly I wrote this because the name on Eli message has a typo, my window is a notification window and is not owned by the current active window and the property still works correctly. if set to true does not remove focus from my currently active window.

Answer (score 5):

In my [recent blog post](http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/wpf-splash-screens), I use [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to bring a window to the front of the z-order without giving it focus. I don't believe WPF has an in-built means of achieving the same without p/invoke.

Comment: Thanks Kent. But this only works if My window is minimized. and not working if window is WindowState.Normal and is hiding behind some app(IE etc..)

Comment: blog link is broken.

Comment: @KentBoogaart the link is broken again

Comment: @Boumbles, updated the link.. apparently the trailing slash was the only problem :O

Answer (score 1):

I needed to solve a similar problem and got it to work by setting Window.ShowActivate=false and then using Window.Show rather than Window.Activate. Perhaps this will work for you. I have not yet needed to use BringIntoView because my window is newly created and appears on top of other windows by default.

Comment: Pinvoke (ShowWindow with "ShowNoActivate) NOT works for me. 
this is a better answer for me, simple "Window.Show". Thanks