# How to avoid window flickering when move focus between windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am facing window flickering when move focus from one window to another window in WPF. For example consider two window named as Front and Back window. In the Back window kept two control **Text box and Button**. when I click the button i have **move the focus to Front window** then move the **focus to Text box in the Back window** immediately, At this time Back window is flickering. Below code is Button click event of Back window.

```
private void FocusFrontWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (frontWindow == null)
        {
            frontWindow = new FrontWindow();
            frontWindow.Show();
        }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => frontWindow.Focus()), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => BackWindowTextBox.Focus()), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

    }
```

How to avoid this flickering? Have you any idea please share with me.

Comment: Why are you using dispatcher (you are already in UI thread)? Also your description doesnt seem clear, if you are focusing on front window and then right away you need to focus back to textbox in backwindow; then how is front window still showing?

Comment: frontWindow.ShowActivated = false;  [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210344/activate-wpf-window-without-losing-focus-on-previous-application-window).